# How to solve a system of nonlinear equations in GF(2)

Tags: systems-of-equations, boolean-algebra

Let's say I have a system of $n$ nonlinear boolean equations and $n$ unknowns like:

$
\begin{cases}
(x_i \oplus \neg x_j) \wedge x_n &=1\\
&\vdots \\
(x_k \wedge x_i \oplus x_j) \wedge \neg x_l &=0
\end{cases}
$

where $i,k,l \leq n$.

What is the most efficient method to solve this kind of systems when $n > 200$ ?

Comment: Are you asking about algorithms or software packages?

Comment: @saulspatz I'm more interested in algorithms but software packages are welcomed!

Comment: You could write your problem as netlist of logical gates, use [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/) to translate it into [Conjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (CNF) and a [SAT solver](https://www.coursera.org/learn/advanced-algorithms-and-complexity/lecture/3JKdg/using-sat-solvers) like [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) or [Cryptominisat](https://github.com/msoos/cryptominisat) to get a solution. An easy alternative is a constraint solver like [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Extended comment:**

Your example written as netlist for [bc2cnf](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/):

```
BC1.1
a1 := (xi ^ !xj) & xn;
a2 := (xk & xi ^ xj) & !xl;
ASSIGN a1, !a2;
```

Shorter form without auxiliary variables:

```
BC1.1
ASSIGN (xi ^ !xj) & xn;
ASSIGN !((xk & xi ^ xj) & !xl);
```

[MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) model:

```
var bool: xi;
var bool: xj;
var bool: xk;
var bool: xl;
var bool: xn;

constraint (xi != not xj) /\ xn;
constraint ((xk /\ xi) != xj) /\ not xl;

solve satisfy;
```